# Updating mysql database with php using variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems updating mysql with php using varables.

```
    mysqli_query($connection,  "UPDATE passwords SET used=1, time_used='{$time}'
                                WHERE password='{$key}'
                               ");
```

I was given the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\key_check.php on line 47
```

any ideas why?

Thanks!

EDIT: Whole Code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W5cx8pBP

The "new mysqli" solution seems to be giving problems when trying to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM passwords", $connection);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: post your mysqli connection code.. $connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection setting must look like

```
$connection = new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$db);
```

Then execute the query using your way or by this way also

```
$query="UPDATE passwords SET used=1, time_used='{$time}'
                            WHERE password='{$key}'
                           ";
$stmt = $connection->query($sql);
```

*note: using prepared statements for mysqli can also possible and great. By somehow you also needed to bind parameters in there..*

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare $connection by creating a new mysqli object. If you fail to do so, you can check the [documentation for mysqli constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Here's the code from the documentation.

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $connection->connect_errno . ') '
            . $connection->connect_error);
```